# Create tables whose information stored in another table using stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to write a stored procedure to create table(s) whose information like table_name, column_name, data_type are stored in another table as below image...

[image: table details]

No need to worry about Primary n Foreign Key specifications.
Is it possible to do that in ORACLE?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You already have that: `select * from user_tab_columns`

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Construct the DDL string in a loop and execute it with `execute immediate`.

For example:

```
begin
    for r in (
        select 'create table ' || td.table_name || chr(10)||'( ' ||
               listagg(rpad(td.column_name,31) || td.data_type, chr(10)||', ') within group (order by id) ||
               ' )' as create_table
        from table_definitions td
        group by td.id, td.table_name
        order by td.id
    )
    loop
        dbms_output.put_line(r.create_table || ';' || chr(10));
        execute immediate r.create_table;
    end loop;
end;
```

Demo setup:

```
create table table_definitions
( id integer   not null
, table_name   varchar2(30) not null
, column_name  varchar2(30) not null, data_type varchar2(30) not null
, constraint   tabdef_uk unique (table_name, column_name) );

insert all
into table_definitions values (1, 'EMP', 'EMP_ID', 'NUMBER')
into table_definitions values (1, 'EMP', 'EMP_NAME', 'VARCHAR2(30)')
into table_definitions values (1, 'EMP', 'SALARY', 'NUMBER')
into table_definitions values (1, 'EMP', 'DEPT_ID', 'NUMBER')
into table_definitions values (2, 'DEPT', 'DEPT_ID', 'NUMBER')
into table_definitions values (2, 'DEPT', 'DEPT_NAME', 'VARCHAR2(30)')
into table_definitions values (2, 'DEPT', 'LOCATION', 'VARCHAR2(30)')
select * from dual;
```

**However**, there are some problems with this whole approach.

I had to add lengths to your `VARCHAR2` columns. You'd need to do the same for the others if you didn't want plain `NUMBER` for every numeric column. Also, there is no column ordering, so they could be generated in any order. I couldn't see the purpose of the `id` column - was it meant to be unique, or unique within `table_name`? And there is no provision for `NOT NULL`, defaults etc.

I would be rather nervous if I came across this in a system had to work on. What is it for?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there will be a better approach, but meanwhile you can work on the below :

Your proc code should be something like this:

```
select distinct id, table_name 
bulk collect into ip_id, ip_tab_name
from tab_details; 

for x in ip_id.first .. ip_id.last loop

select column_name, data_type bulk collect into v_col_name,
v_data_type from tab_Details where id= ip_id(x);

v_sql := 'create table ' || ip_tab_name(x) || ' ( col1 number) ';

execute immediate v_sql;

for i in v_col_name.first .. v_col_name.last  loop

v_sql1 := 'alter table ' || ip_tab_name(x) || ' add ' || v_col_name(i)
|| '  ' || v_data_type(i);

execute immediate v_sql1;

end loop; -- (for i loop)

v_sql2 := 'alter table ' || ip_tab_name(x) || ' drop column col1 ';

execute immediate v_sql2;

end loop;-- (for x loop)
```